# Countable & uncountable nouns in the same sentence

Tags: grammar

Which one is grammatically correct:
1. There is food and drinks at X Cafe. 
Or
2. There are food and drinks at X Cafe.

(This is for a class test paper).

Thanks 
EC

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include what you think is correct and why. It will help users understand your problem. Otherwise, your question may be closed. See [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4785#4785).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that neither of your sentences are idiomatic (or even necessarily grammatical).

It can be confusing though, because general usage around this is a bit inconsistent.

For instance:

> I ate **the** bacon and **eggs** (dish) that **was** served to me this morning.

Here, *bacon* is singular and *eggs* is plural, even though the *dish itself* is referred to in the singular.

(Note that some people may still use the plural verb **were**, and it may also be more common to do so in the UK.)

If we really want to specify a single strip of bacon and just one egg, then the sentence would need to be rephrased:

> I ate **both** the one piece of bacon and the single **egg** that **were** served to me this morning.

Here, the use of **both** emphasizes the individuality of each item, indicating that they should be treated as separate objects, thereby making their combination plural.

---

In your sentence, unlike *bacon and eggs*, it's common to use the singular *drink*:

> There **is** **food and drink** at X Cafe.

This sounds less awkward than either *there* ***is*** *food and* ***drinks*** or *there* ***are food*** *and* ***drinks***. (But the fact that it sounds less awkward has more to do with common usage than with actual syntax.)

---

However, other variations can be used that will avoid all problems with singularity and plurality:

> There **are** many **types** of food and drink at X Cafe.

Here, the plural *are* applies to *types*, and both *types of food* and *types of drink* are grammatical on their own, so their conjunction also works without a problem.

> There is much **to eat and drink** at X Cafe.

Here, the nouns are replaced by verbs, bypassing any potential issue with plurality.